# How can I make my DataGridView perform like this in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have *DataGridView* that contains *ID, Name, Description, Quantity, Duration, and Price* for a List of Services in a certain Veterinary. It's outcome would look like a pile of lists(Form1) from 1 to "n". Is there a way for it when double clicked from the list it will go into another form where it will be placed in Textboxes respectively(Form3)?

Comment: What do you want to double click? A row? The whole DataGridView? It's a little unclear what you're asking. If you could also provide a mock-up of what your DataGridView would look like that would also help.

Comment: **very unclear** does the technical term `pile of lists` mean the DGV will contain many lists?  and when you click an item what does `it` refer to that you want to go to Form3, the list item or the entire list?

Comment: @MurDeR uhm, yes. a certain row from the list. I'll try to make a screen shot of it once I have finished the other parts of it.

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, multiple entries in the list. Like for example, The list is on Form1. There are 3 entries that is currently in that list. Now I wish to select the 2nd entry. When I double click that entry/row, that entry would appear in Form3 which there are textboxes pertaining to its ID Name Description Quantity Duration and Price.

Comment: if the DGV contains all the data from the list, just copy the contents to the controls on the other form.  If the DGV is a digest of the items, you may need some hidden columns to identify the source list and index represented by each row...or maybe a cell with the list object in it.  Are these lists `List(Of T)` or are you using the term loosely?